# Is this a safe and correct way to save file to internal memory?

Tags: android, memory, save

I've been using the following code, but intuitively I see it's not too safe. Will it work flawlessly in every device? This code copies to internal memory my main database (100 kB) in the first app run. Thanks for your time.

```
private void CopyDBtoInternal() {

    String path = "/data/data/com.myproject/databases/";
    String DB_DESTINATION = "/data/data/com.myproject/databases/sample.db";

    // Check if the database exists before copying
    boolean initialiseDatabase = (new File(DB_DESTINATION)).exists();
    if (initialiseDatabase == false) {

        //create folders
        File db_folder = new File(path);
        db_folder.mkdirs();

        AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();

        try {
            InputStream is = assetManager.open("sample.db");

            // Copy the database into the destination
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(DB_DESTINATION);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0){
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            os.flush();

            os.close();
            is.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(AppGuiaDeBulas.this);
            dialogo.setTitle("Alerta");
            dialogo.setMessage("It was not possible to save database. Error #001");
            dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
            dialogo.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this part of the article on writing to storage.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles)

If you're using API Level 8 (Froyo) or greater, use [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) to open a File that represents the external storage directory where you should save your files. This method takes a type parameter that specifies the type of subdirectory you want, such as DIRECTORY_MUSIC and DIRECTORY_RINGTONES (pass null to receive the root of your application's file directory). This method will create the appropriate directory if necessary. By specifying the type of directory, you ensure that the Android's media scanner will properly categorize your files in the system (for example, ringtones are identified as ringtones and not music). If the user uninstalls your application, this directory and all its contents will be deleted.

If you're using API Level 7 or lower, use [getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29), to open a File representing the root of the external storage. You should then write your data in the following directory:

/Android/data//files/
The  is your Java-style package name, such as "com.example.android.app". If the user's device is running API Level 8 or greater and they uninstall your application, this directory and all its contents will be deleted.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm using API Level 3 for a broader range of users for my app. I want to save my tiny database to internal memory instead of external storage. Or isn't it a good practice?